# deploy error - trigger to create task based on lead comments field update

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

trigger to create task based on lead comments field update
hi i am test a trigger which is able to create a NEW task based on lead comments field been changed, the trigger works now, and i need help to fix unit test code issue which is show "Test coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required" when i validrate under production before deploy.

Trigger code - it works in sandbox

```
trigger CreateUpdateTask02 on Lead (after update) {

List<Task> NewTasks = new List<Task>();
for(Lead updatedLead:Trigger.new){
    if((updatedLead.Comments__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedLead.Id).Comments__c)&&   (updatedLead.Comments__c !=null)){
        NewTasks.add(new Task(
            ActivityDate = Date.today(),
            WhoID = updatedLead.Id,
            Status = 'Not Started',
            type = 'Other',
            Priority = 'Normal',
            Subject = 'trigger Comment changed',
            description = updatedLead.Comments__c
        ));
    }
}

insert lNewTasks;

}
```

Unit test class - 100% cover under sandbox, but error in prod 
"Test coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required"

```
   @isTest
   public class UnitTests_CreateUpdateTask02 {

   static testMethod void CreateUpdateTask02() {

   // Switch to the runtime context
   test.startTest();  

   Lead record = new Lead(
        FirstName='Test firstName',
        LastName = 'Test LastName',
        Comments__c = 'Test Comment new'
        );    

   insert record;
   System.debug('Created and inserted lead');

   record.Comments__c = 'Test Comment upadted 100';

   update record;
   System.debug('update existing lead comments');

   LIST<Lead> records = [SELECT ID, Comments__c FROM Lead WHERE FirstName='Test firstName'];

   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

   tasks.add(new Task(
      ActivityDate = Date.today(),
      WhoId = records[0].Id,
      Status = 'Not Started',
      type='Other',
      Priority='Normal',
      Subject='trigger Comment changed',
      Description = records[0].Comments__c
   ));

   insert tasks;
   System.debug('Created and inserted task');

   // query for the new teak created and assert that the comments was added correctly
   Task comment = [SELECT Id,WhoId,Subject,Description,ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE Subject='trigger Comment changed' LIMIT 1];


   //validate test
    System.assertEquals(record.Id, comment.WhoId);
    System.assertEquals(Date.Today(), comment.ActivityDate);
    System.assertEquals('trigger Comment changed', comment.Subject);
    System.assertEquals('Test Comment upadted 100', comment.Description);

    // Switch back to the original context
   Test.stopTest();

    }

     }
```

Comment: How are you deploying the trigger? Did you remember to include the test class when deploying?

Comment: yes, i did add unit test class to change set as well, and both are under inbound change set of production...

Comment: Is the unit test showing any errors, or just that the trigger isn't covered?

Comment: there is no error, and it seems just code coverage issue - the message "Test coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required" .

Comment: for the unit test code, i also run test under force.com IDE, and it displays "0 lines not tested, 100% covered." thanks

Comment: Also, under sandbox, the overall code coverage is currently 84%. To deploy code to production, you must have at least 75%.

Comment: The 75% minimum is a separate issue, though; yours is failing because it is having 0% on the trigger, when triggers must have at least 1% (unlike other Apex, which could have 0% for any class.)

Comment: If the after update trigger is part of the changeset, then it won't execute if the insert or update on the Lead in the testmethod fails - such as via a validation rule in PROD not present in sandbox.  You could go to SFDC workbench in PROD and manually do the DML of your testmethod to verify that the insert and update DML truly execute in PROD

Comment: yeah, i got figure out here, the thing is the unit test class need to deploy as well as i just add it to the inbound change set. i got the trigger deploy for now, thanks all.

Comment: That was literally the first thing you were asked... Please try to do better in the future. We don't want to waste the communities time with these types of issues...